# Drawing rectangles in corrplot using corrRect not working when using a mixed plot

Tags: r, r-corrplot

I can draw rectangles in a normal correlation matrix using corrplot, e.g.:

```
library(corrplot) 
corrplot(cor(mtcars)) %>%
corrRect(name = c("mpg", "qsec", "carb"))
```

But when using this mixed corrplot:

```
corrplot.mixed(cor(mtcars)) %>%
corrRect(name = c("mpg", "qsec", "carb"))
```

I get this error message:

> Error in if (type == "upper") { : argument is of length zero

How to make it work in a mixed corrplot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [source](https://github.com/taiyun/corrplot/blob/0497ad6717c2909fb1ed0c75ff6d269605107808/R/corrRect.R#L88) for `corrRect` contains the line `if (type == "upper")`. `type` is defined in the function as `type = corrRes$arg$type`, where `corrRes` is the correlation plot you pass in the first argument.

The first plot you created has the `type` property (run `corrplot(cor(mtcars))$arg$type` and the output will be `"full"`).

However, plots created with `corrplot.mixed()` do not have a value for `$arg$type`. So we need to create one.

As your correlation plot is not an `upper` (or `lower`) triangular plot, we can assign the value `"full"` to `type`. This will allow you to get past the `if()` statement which causes an error and does not relate to your plot, and to ultimately create the rectangles in the same place.

```r
p  <- corrplot.mixed(cor(mtcars), tl.pos = "lt")
p$arg$type  <- "full"
corrRect(p, name = c("mpg", "qsec", "carb"))
```

Note: make sure to set `tl.pos = "lt"` to show the text labels. You can change `diag = "l"` if you want to show the correlation of 1.00 of every column with itself, rather than having a blank square.

#### Output

[image]